# How does one retrieve the entity body from a request in Node.js/Express (for CSP violation reporting)?

Tags: node.js, http, express, content-security-policy

I am interested in implementing a Content Security Policy (CSP) for my Node.js application. Mozilla's docs are rather helpful but I am stuck at how to enable [violation reports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Security/CSP/Using_CSP_violation_reports). I understand the basic premise of how they work (the browser sends a POST request to the specified URL to notify the website of a violation) but could not figure out where to find the JSON document describing the violation in the HTTP request. Perhaps this would have been obvious to someone more familiar with the HTTP spec.

Looking at the [W3C draft](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html#report-uri) for CSP, I established that the JSON is contained in a portion of the HTTP called the "entity body". I still don't know what the purpose of the entity is (the only mildly useful page I could find on the matter was one from the HTTP spec). I am assuming it the body of the request.

Perhaps more importantly, I cannot find any way to retrieve the contents of the entity body. I thought of using `req.header('entity-body')` but that doesn't work as the entity is not a HTTP header. What is it and how to I fetch it?

(Additionally, I tried finding a tutorial on how to implement CSP violation reporting in Node.js and found nothing. I did find one for PHP but it wasn't particularly helpful, referencing a `file_get_contents('php://input')` which I don't have anything similar to in Node.js/Express.)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I was over-analyzing things. All you need to do is enable the `express.bodyParser()` middleware for express and then fetch `req.body` in the POST event handler. This retrieves the body of the HTTP request containing the JSON violation report.

Enable middleware:

```
var server = express.createServer(
    // other middleware here
    express.bodyParser()
);
```

Retrieving violation report:

```
server.post('/csp/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer to the question you should accept it so that people know that the question has been answered (it's fine to accept your own answer). You do this by clicking the tick next to the answer.

Comment: I tried that but was informed that I have to wait three days before accepting my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I went through some difficulties getting my `Express` app fronted with Nginx to report `csp violations` and the two things I learned from the above answer were:

1. Should be `POST` method and not `GET` method
2. `req.body` contains the report

But, the above was not sufficient and I kept getting empty `req.body` and I could not find any other post to describe how to fix it. After some research I came across this [post](https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/http-security-headers/csp/) as well as a totally isolated github [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/issues/20) where `dougwilson` give hints where to put the route that handles the `csp report`.

The reason the `req.body` was empty for me was because I placed the `csp report` route handler after the following configs:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

I moved the `csp report` route handler above these but, I still kept getting empty `req.body` then I added the following above `csp report` route handler to get the report in `req.body`

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/csp-report' }));
```

After adding the above line above `csp report` request handler, `Express` understood that it should parse requests that have Content-type as `application/csp-report`.

Maybe `Express` by default do not parse `application/csp-report`, and adding the above **resolved** the issue for me. I also googled if `Express` parses `application/csp-report` by default and I came across this [gist](https://gist.github.com/oroce/361d1abda643d1b6a95d) claiming that `Chrome` sends `application/csp-report` whereas Firefox sends `application/json` (and I am using Chrome - you can include `application/json` also if you face issues with `FF`).

So this is how it looks in my `app.js`

```
// without following csp-report don't get parsed.
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/csp-report' }));

app.get('/vehicle/cspreport', function(req, res) {
  res.status(403);
});

app.post('/vehicle/cspreport', function(req, res) {
  console.log('csp report > ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
...
```

The accepted answer posted by OP is from `2011` and I thought of adding an answer to show how I resolved this issue in `2016` with the following versions of Node.js, Express and Nginx

```
Node: v4.2.4
Express: 4.13.1 
Nginx: 1.8.1
```